# HTML5 document and itemscope error

Tags: html, w3c-validation, microdata

I am trying to validate my HTML5 document with Microdata, but I am receiving a very strange error and I don't know what to do here:

> Line 1, Column 14242: The `itemtype` attribute must not be specified on elements that do not have an `itemscope` attribute specified.
>
> ```html
> …mtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">Company…
> ```

This is my HTML code:

```html
<span itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemprop="hiringOrganization">
  <span itemprop="name">Company</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I have added an itemscope in this way: <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemprop="hiringOrganization"> - and it has worked! But is this the right way?

Comment: Yes it is. You can have itemscope without itemtype, but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Microdata specification (Working Draft), [section "Typed items"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-microdata-20121025/#typed-items):

> The type for an item is given as the value of an `itemtype` attribute on the same element as the `itemscope` attribute.

So it should be:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemprop="hiringOrganization">
  <span itemprop="name">Company</span>
</span>
```